# When is the dual coframe of an orthonormal frame closed?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry, differential-forms

Let $E_1,E_2$ be a smooth **orthonormal** frame of vector fields on a simply connected open domain $U \subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$.

Let $E^i$ be the associated dual coframe of one-forms, and suppose that $dE^i=0$.

It is true that the $E_i$ are constants? (do not change from point to point).

I know that $E^i=du_i$ or equivalently that $E_i=\nabla u_i$ where the $u_i$ are smooth functions on $U$, but I am not sure how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the map $u:U\to\mathbb{R}^2$ whose coordinates are the $u_i$.  The assumption that the $E_i$ are orthonormal says that $u$ is a local isometry.  But an isometry between two open subsets of Euclidean space must be given by a rigid motion, and the connectedness of $U$ then implies that $u$ is globally the restriction of some rigid motion to $U$.  In particular $u$ is an affine map, and so its derivative is constant.

(Note that the assumption that $U$ is simply connected is not necessary--you can just apply this argument locally to conclude that the $E_i$ are locally constant and hence constant if $U$ is connected.)

Answer (score 2):

The coframe $1$-forms are both closed if and only if the connection form is $0$. If the Riemannian metric is flat (has zero curvature), you can *choose* an orthonormal frame so that this will be the case, but it need not be. (Consider the case of polar coordinates on an appropriate open subset of $\Bbb R^2-\{0\}$.)

Comment: Thank you for this interesting answer. I think that what you say is not exactly accurate: The forms $E^i$ must be constants (see Eric Wofsey's answer). In your example on $\Bbb R^2-\{0\}$, the *orthonormal* coframe $dr,rd\theta$ is not closed; $d(rd\theta)=dr \wedge d\theta \neq 0$. I think it would be interesting to prove that the $E^i$ are constants using Cartan's formalism, which is what you seems to be doing here.

Comment: That was precisely my point. I said that on a flat surface (and this is true more generally) you can *choose* an orthonormal frame (and dual coframe) to make the connection form $0$. Polar coordinates was an example of a situation where it is not, despite the $0$ curvature. (Note the "but it need not be" in my sentence.) :) Indeed, finding the *correct* framing for which the connection form vanishes gives you a coframe in which the $1$-forms are exact and you get your (local) isometry with the Euclidean plane from that, precisely as Eric did. Yes, I'm a Chern student, so go Cartan!